# Is there any way to print a resolved TypeScript type?

Tags: typescript, types

I was reading about [TypeScript 2.8 - Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) and I saw a lot of examples in the Typescript docs where they list the *resolved?* version of a type as comments next to it:

```
type TypeName<T> =
    T extends string ? "string" :
    T extends number ? "number" :
    T extends boolean ? "boolean" :
    T extends undefined ? "undefined" :
    T extends Function ? "function" :
    "object";

type T0 = TypeName<string>;  // "string"
type T1 = TypeName<"a">;  // "string"
type T2 = TypeName<true>;  // "boolean"
type T3 = TypeName<() => void>;  // "function"
type T4 = TypeName<string[]>;  // "object"
```

For example `TypeName<true>` is actually `boolean`. This becomes even more useful with even more complex scenarios, where you can see what type you've actually constructed:

```
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never }[keyof T];
type FunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, FunctionPropertyNames<T>>;

type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T];
type NonFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;

interface Part {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    subparts: Part[];
    updatePart(newName: string): void;
}

type T40 = FunctionPropertyNames<Part>;  // "updatePart"
type T41 = NonFunctionPropertyNames<Part>;  // "id" | "name" | "subparts"
type T42 = FunctionProperties<Part>;  // { updatePart(newName: string): void }
type T43 = NonFunctionProperties<Part>;  // { id: number, name: string, subparts: Part[] }
```

That could certainly help me when confusion about types arise, so I was wondering if there is any way to have the compiler extract that same type information?

Comment: You mean other then hovering in vs code over a type to see the resolved type ? Do you want some sort of command line utility to do this using the compiler API ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I've never used VS code, does it already provide this functionality?

Comment: Yes it does, I can provide an answer with a screenshot if it helps :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Ah nice, I didn't know that. Yeah that'd be great :)

Comment: Related answers: Using an [invalid assignment trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66124742/3002584), Using [`ts-node`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55777714/3002584), or using [compiler API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67235137/3002584). Also take a look at  [Implementing an `Expand<T>` type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/3002584).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio code already provides this functionality if you hover over a conditional type. For your example this is what it looks like :

[image]

Comment: For larger types it has a lot of `...` in it, is there anyway to get the full type and to be able to copy paste it? I tried this but it doesnt work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67235137/1828637

Answer (score 1):

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/540776) came one year later and I still find it useful:

```
// expands object types one level deep
export type DebugExpand<T> = T extends infer O
  ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] }
  : never;

// expands object types recursively
export type DebugExpandRecursive<T> = T extends object
  ? T extends infer O
    ? { [K in keyof O]: DebugExpandRecursive<O[K]> }
    : never
  : T;
```

Credits to its author, I just renamed/formatted them.

Comment: is this not when you should dup-vote?

Comment: I found another question on same topic which was more recent, and I voted for duplication. But this one is older is instead, plus it has an accepted answer. Did not seem like a duplicate to me.