# How to examine a type in typescript's repl (ts-node)?

Tags: typescript, ts-node

So I have the following entered

```
type Duck = {
    colors: string;
    featheres: number;
}

type DuckProps = keyof Duck
```

how do I examine/verify that for example `DuckProps` is of value: `'colors' | 'feathers'`?

I can't seem to console log or use it as it will just return

```
[eval].ts:8:7 - error TS2693: 'DuckProps' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

How do you interact with the typesript specific constructs (interface, type, etc.) via the repl? In other words, when i type Duck. I expect something to show up like this:

> $ Duck

```
Duck<Typescript type> { color: string; feathers: number }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bit of a hack but gets the job done. Using the `.type` command we can coerce the type we are interested in into a statement and get `ts-node` to display the quick info associated with it.

```js
> type Duck = {
...    colors: string;
...    featheres: number;
...  }
undefined
> type DuckProps = keyof Duck
undefined
> .type _ as DuckProps
type DuckProps = "colors" | "featheres"
```

**Caveat:** this only works with named types at the end. What happens underneath is that `.type` calls typescript's `getQuickInfoAtPosition` with the position at the end of the input. Like ctrl hover in the typescript playground, and that bottom grey line is what is displayed in addition to some documentation to go with it.

This seems like a useful feature from ts-node and might warrant a feature request.

Comment: Nice! just a note to others, if DuckProps isn't a thing, the commandline will display `any`. Thanks!

Comment: `.type _ as DuckProps` results in just `type DuckProps = keyof Duck` for me in `ts-node`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to ensure that no one will use the type `Duck` with non-existent property names. In the code sample below, I check that the property does exist on `Duck` and it's of the right type:

```
type Duck = {
    colors: string;
    featheres: number;
}

function doStuff<T, P extends keyof T>(
    property: P,
    value: T[P],
    obj: T) {

   // Do something     
}

const myDuck = {
    colors: "red",
    featheres: 123
};

doStuff('colors', 'red', myDuck);
doStuff('featheres', 100, myDuck); 
doStuff('colors', 123, myDuck); // error: the value of the wrong type
doStuff('colours', 'red', myDuck); // error: misspelled prop name
```

Comment: Not quite, I want to `repl` and get feedbacks from the command line about what the types are. So when i type Duck. I expect something to show up like this: Duck<Typescript type> { color: string; feathers: number }

Answer (score -1):

keyof Duck won't give you a type, just value,
you should use:

let duckProps = keyof Duck;