# Can I get TypeScript to reveal what type it has determined for an expression?

Tags: typescript

I have some code like the following where I want to determine what type TypeScript has inferred for an expression:

```
var timer = window.setTimeout(...);
/* QUESTION: What is the inferred type of "timer" here? */
```

When I use the mypy typechecker for Python, I can insert the special expression `reveal_type(my_expression)` into code to have the typechecker print a fake error containing the inferred type for expression `my_expression`.

Is there a way I can ask the TypeScript `tsc` type-checker for similar information about the inferred type of an expression?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything built into TS that allows you to do that; however, if you're using a modern IDE like VSC, it will show you the type it has determined based on either documentation or the type definitions. If you don't have a modern IDE, you can examine the type definition yourself (usually in a .ts or .d.ts file).

Comment: If you are using VS Code, moving your mouse over the variable shows it.

Comment: Using VSCode with TypeScript, you can see the type if you hover your mouse over the identifier. However, if the type is long or complicated, VS Code will substitute portions (and sometimes most) of the inferred type with `...`. This makes the tooltip smaller, but now you do not know the full type inferred by TypeScript/VSCode!

Comment: The mouse hover function sometimes gives exactly what I want, but in other cases it just gives me the name with zero further explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of an equivalent to `reveal_type`, but you can force an invalid assignment and inspect the resulting error message. Assignment to [never](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) always fails<sup>1</sup>, so in your example:

```
var timer = window.setTimeout(...);
const revealType : never = timer;
```

Should cause the compiler to print:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless the type you're checking is also `never`

Comment: Very smart suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not really unfold the type variables in my case so this also seems like a "best of luck" style solution.