# Extract typescript function return type to interface in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

VSCode is able to show the return types of a function.
How can the definition be extracted to an interface?

[image: sample function devinition showing static types]

One way of retrieving the return type is using the inbuilt `ReturnType` utility, but in this case I want to have a snapshot of the current situation to use as typings for an api client. If the types of the function change in the future I do not want to automatically update the api client in order to spot changes.

```js
type ReturnedType = ReturnType<typeof prepareBookingData>;
```

Another small workaround is to specify `noErrorTruncation:true` in the tsconfigs compilerOption as proposed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64566#issuecomment-590140308), but this still gets us there 80% of the way and it should be possible with a single click and a quick action.

[image]

How can I extract a function's return type?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67222224/print-typescript-types-into-console-file)

Comment: @kwyntes it points me in the right direction to write an extension myself (which is what I am currently doing), I just would have hoped that there already is an existing solution out there

Comment: @Killian Actually I just though of something. If you write a call to a function that doesn't exist, VSCode will suggest to add the missing function declaration, which will then include a type declaration for the parameters. Then you can simply copy/paste the parameter type definition into an interface.

Comment: @kwyntes wonderful, thank you very much. I still believe it should be a bit easier but I would have never thought about this approach and it is working good enough for what I am intending. 

My vscode plugin got as far as compiling the code, and printing the signature to the source code but it is not correctly formated because I am building the interface declaration myself without using the compilers factory method. Currently I am stuck here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77386997/typescript-factory-create-interface-from-function-return-type but will reach out to their discord soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VSCode's quick fixes to achieve this. Writing a call to a function that does not exist with the value of your desired type as an argument passed to it, you VSCode will suggest to add the missing function declaration for you.

Here's an example with a type constructed from a parser combinator library.

[image: VSCode suggesting the fix]

Results in:

[image]

It even automatically imports missing types for you!