# Typescript factory create interface from function return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

How can signature or ts.Type extracted from the AST be passed into the factory method for reuse? The ulitmate goal is to take a return type of a function and create an interface for it.

```
 import * as ts from "typescript";


 const signature = typeChecker.getSignatureFromDeclaration(node);
 const retType = signature?.getReturnType();

 ts.factory.createInterfaceDeclaration(
   undefined,
   "interfaceName",
   undefined,
   undefined,
   //How to pass the extracted signature from above inside here?
   [retType]
);
```

If it is necessary to traverse the tree how to get the SyntaxKind?

```
const properties = retType.getProperties();
properties.map((property) => {
  const propertyName = property.getName();
  const valueDeclaration = property.valueDeclaration;
  const typeOfParameter = typeChecker.getTypeOfSymbol(property);

  const questionToken = undefined;
  //   const questionToken =
  //     valueDeclaration !== undefined
  //       ? ts.factory.createToken(ts.SyntaxKind.QuestionToken)
  //       : undefined;

  //TODO how to get those?
  const keywordTypeNode = ts.factory.createKeywordTypeNode(
    ts.SyntaxKind.NumberKeyword
  );

  ts.factory.createPropertySignature(
    undefined,
    propertyName,
    questionToken,
    keywordTypeNode
  );
});
```